# Entity Framework not picking up Transaction Scope

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure-sql-database, transactionscope

I have pretty much standard EF 6.1 'create object in a database' code wrapped in transaction scope. For whatever reason the data persists in db after the transaction fails (to complete).

Code:

```
using (var db = this.Container.Resolve<SharedDataEntities>()) // << new instance of DbContext
{
    using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
    {
        SubscriptionTypes st = this.SubscriptionType.Value;

        if (st == SubscriptionTypes.Lite && this.ProTrial)
            st = SubscriptionTypes.ProTrial;

        Domain domain = new Domain()
        {
            Address = this.Address.Trim(),
            AdminUserId = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey,
            AdminUserName = user.UserName,
            Description = this.Description.TrimSafe(),
            DomainKey = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Enabled = !masterSettings.DomainEnableControlled.Value,
            Name = this.Name.Trim(),
            SubscriptionType = (int)st,
            Timezone = this.Timezone,
            Website = this.Website.TrimSafe(),
            IsPrivate = this.IsPrivate
        };

        foreach (var countryId in this.Countries)
        {
            domain.DomainCountries.Add(new DomainCountry() { CountryId = countryId, Domain = domain });
        }

        db.Domains.Add(domain);
        db.SaveChanges(); // << This is the Saving that should not be commited until we call 'ts.Complete()'

        this.ResendActivation(domain); // << This is where the Exception occurs

        using (TransactionScope ts2 = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
        {
            this.DomainMembership.CreateDomainUser(domain.Id, (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey, user.UserName, DomainRoles.DomainSuperAdmin | DomainRoles.Driver);
            ts2.Complete();
        }
        this.Enabled = domain.Enabled;
        ts.Complete();  // << Transaction commit never happens 
    }
}
```

After SaveChanges() exception is thrown inside ResendActivation(...) so the changes should not be saved. However the records stay in database.

There is no other TransactionScope wrapping the code that I've pasted, it's triggered by an MVC Action call.

Comment: try creating your first transaction scope like this `new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions(){IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted})`

Answer (score 3):

after more investigations, turns out that something - probably Entity Framework upgrade or database update process had put

```
Enlist=false;
```

into the database connection string. That effectively stops EF from picking up Transaction Scope.

So the solution is to set it to true, or remove it, I think by default it's true

Answer (score 2):

Try using the transaction from the db instance it self, db.Database.BeginTransaction() if I recall it correctly instead of using the transaction scope.

```
using (var ts = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
..
}
```

Assuming that db is your entity framework context.

Comment: That could prob work, but it's not fixing the code that I've posted. The code I've posted should work the way it is

Comment: Note, `context.Database.BeginTransaction()` is only available on EF6+.

Answer (score 0):

Context class by default support transactions. but with every new instance of context class, a new transaction will be created. This new transaction is a nested transaction and it will get committed once the SaveChanges() on the associated context class gets called.

In the given code it seems, we are calling a method that is responsible for creating a domain user i.e. CreateDomainUser and perhaps that has its own context object. thus this problem.

If this is the case(that this method has own context) the perhaps we don't even need TransactionScope here. We can simply pass the same context(that we are using before this call) to the function that is creating the domain user. We can then check for result of both operations and if they are successful, we simply need to call SaveChanges() method.

TransactionScope is usually needed when we are mixing ADO.NET calls with Entity framework. We can use it with context also, but it would be an overkill as the context class already has a transaction and we can simply use the same context to manage the transaction.  If this is the case in the above code then the trick to fix the issue is to let the context class know that you want to use it with your own transaction. Since the transaction gets associated with the connection object in the scope, we need to use the context class with the connection that is being associated with the transaction scope. Also, we need to let the context class know that it cannot own the connection as it is being owned by the calling code. so we can do something like:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required)) 
{ 
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("...")) 
    { 
        conn.Open(); 

        var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(); 
        sqlCommand.Connection = conn; 
        sqlCommand.CommandText = 
            @"UPDATE Blogs SET Rating = 5" + 
                " WHERE Name LIKE '%Entity Framework%'"; 
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

        using (var context = 
            new BloggingContext(conn, contextOwnsConnection: false)) 
        { 
            var query = context.Posts.Where(p => p.Blog.Rating > 5); 
            foreach (var post in query) 
            { 
                post.Title += "[Cool Blog]"; 
            } 
            context.SaveChanges(); 
        } 
    } 

    scope.Complete(); 
}
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `TransactionScope` with EF, I know our projects do.  However, I think you want the EF context instantiated inside the transaction scope -- that is, I believe you need to swap the outermost / first two `using` statements, as the answer from @rahuls suggests.

Even if it works the other way ... if you have a service / app / business layer method that needs to update several tables, and you want those updates to be atomic, you'd need to do it this way.  So for the sake of consistency (and your own sanity), I would recommend transaction scope first, context second.